# Is there a way to send the data from the web form to the microsoft botframework web client without opening the web client?

Tags: botframework

We have a Angular application with .Net core.

1. When the users type on the input from their web page form field, it will need to be passed to the Microsoft BOT framework.
2. The response message from the BOT service will need to be displayed back to the Bot Chat client.
3. Users will review the above response and have the ability to send the received data from Bot Client back to the web page form fields.

I have read about the Web chat client and the Direct Line bot.
I can use Web chat client but I am not sure how to pass the input from my web form to it as I don't want the user to open the web chat to enter the same data again.
If I use the Direct Line Bot, I have control on passing the form input to the Bot service. In this case, I will need to spend time to build the Web client to display and process the messages.

Comment: Before I answer, is it safe to assume you're going to be using V4 of the chat client?

Comment: Yes, v4 will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by utilizing the DirectLine connection instance that you give to the WebChat control when you create it. The connection instance will enable you to both send events into the bot as well as watch for events coming out of the connection. At the same time, since you're sharing the connection with the chat control, the chat control can perform its typical duties of sending and receiving/displaying message contents.

For example, when the user clicks on the submit button on your form, you would utilize the connection object to send an event that contains your payload like so:

#### Setup DirectLine connection

Create the DirectLine connection at start up and assign it to your WebChat control, but also hold onto the connection object in a variable you can utilize in other places such as the form button click.

```
const directLineToken = await getDirectLineToken();
const directLineConnection = createDirectLine({ directLineToken });
```

#### Form button click logic

In the form button click logic you can now send an `event` activity that represents your proprietary backchannel event to the bot containing the form details as the payload:

```
const fancyFormEventPayload = {
  fieldA: fieldAFormElement.value,
  fieldB: fieldBFormElement.value,
  // etc
};

// NOTE: this returns an observable that you can wait on 
// to watch for errors or know when it has completed. I'm 
// just using fire and forget here for now
directLineConnection.postActivity({
  type: "event",
  name: "myFancyFormSubmitted",
  value: fancyFormEventPayload,
});
```

#### Listening for events coming back

Now the bot might respond with some message activities which the WebChat would then display, but it could also send back an `event` activity that contains the updated form payload which you could watch for and grab to populate the form with the updated values if they say "yes" for that.

```
// The connection exposes the stream of incoming activities via Rx, so
// we create filtered subscription that will process only the activity
// we're interested in and update the form fields in response to that
directLineConnection.activity$
  .filter(activity => activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'myFancyFormUpdate')
  .subscribe(activity =>
  {
    const myFancyFormPayload = activity.value;

    fieldAFormElement.value = myFancyFormPayload.fieldA;
    fieldBFormElement.value = myFancyFormPayload.fieldB;
    // etc
  });
```

Comment: Okay, this gives an idea on how to approach it. Is there any working samples towards this that we can try?

Comment: There are lots of samples in the repo (link below), but I'm not sure any of them go over this specific extensibility point. 

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples